# Remove From Substring On Python

Tags: python, string

I want to remove from the url on in Python. So basically if the string is `HELLLO MOTOTOOOOOO http://moto.com yes` the string should only read `HELLLO MOTOTOOOOOO`. I know how to remove a certain amount of characters, and I know how to remove a substring, but I don't know how to remove from a substring to the end.

From the `http` on should be good.

Comment: Do you always want to keep only the first two words and discard the rest? Is there something in the strings that designates what you want to keep and what you want to discard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

find returns the position.  Then just use slicing:

```
p = mystring.find("http:")
substring = mystring[:p]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Your string
my_string = "HELLLO MOTOTOOOOOO http://moto.com yes"

#index will hold the starting index of 'http'
index = my_string.find("http")

#Create a substring from 0 (the start of the string) to index (where http starts)
my_string[0:index]
```

output:

```
'HELLLO MOTOTOOOOOO '
```